# div background not floating properly

Tags: html, css, background

I have a layout with a left-floating div and non-floating divs.  The text in these divs float nicely to the right but the background does not.  Changing these non-floaters to float:right doesn't help, I don't want the text over there.

Here is demo code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: Blue;
  color: white;
}

div.left_div {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: black;
}

div.t_div {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_div">
  Here is the left div
  <p>not much of interest here.
</div>
Here is some loose text. Here is some more.

<div class="t_div">
  This text floats nicely but the background does not!
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Backgrounds don't float; elements do. Please revise to add a better explanation.

Comment: I would encourage you to abandon floats in general in favor of [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Floats are troublesome, as you've seen, and there are better ways to position boxes these days.

Comment: display:inline-block to the element?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what do you want to achieve, but I assume you want your divs to display next to each other.
Since you are trying this with `float` please try this on `div.t_div`

```
div.t_div {
    color: black;
    background: white;
    float: left; // new code
}
```

Or consider using `display: flex` on the parent element.

Comment: Changing t_div to display:flex seems to work.  I haven't yet learned how to use flex, I guess it's time!

Comment: Oops.  t_div can do very strange things to its content as a flex.  I get columns in the div!  More research needed...

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: Blue;
  color: white;
}

div.left_div {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: black;
}

div.t_div {
  color: black;
  background: white;
  overflow:auto; /* simply add this */
}
```

```html
<div class="left_div">
  Here is the left div
  <p>not much of interest here.
</div>
Here is some loose text. Here is some more.

<div class="t_div">
  This text floats nicely but the background does not!
</div>
```